# How to find all columns that are used in stored procedures of database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to see list of all columns and tables used by all stored procedures  (+views and functions) in a database.

EXAMPLE:

```
create procedure proc as
   select tab1.a,tab2.d,tab2.e
   from tab1
   join tab2 on tab1.b = tab2.b
   where tab1.c = 'filter'
end
```

output:

```
tab1.a
tab1.b
tab1.c
tab2.b
tab2.d
tab2.e
```

I need to see ALL columns referenced by ANY code in database. Thank you.

Comments are welcome.

Comment: You should know that if any of your stored procedures use dynamic SQL, then this cannot be done reliably.

Comment: Let assume I don't use dynamic sql

Answer (score 5):

```
create proc usp_test1
as
begin
select name,object_id from test
end

create proc usp_test2
as
begin
select * from test1
end
```

executing below code gives me

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
O.name SP_Name,T.name Table_Name,c.name Field_Name
FROM sys.sysdepends D 
JOIN sys.sysobjects O ON O.id = D.id
JOIN sys.sysobjects T ON T.id = D.depid
JOIN sys.columns C ON C.column_id=d.depnumber
and C.object_id=D.depID
WHERE O.xtype = 'P'


SP_Name Table_Name  Field_Name
usp_test1   test    name
usp_test1   test    object_id
usp_test2   test1   create_date
usp_test2   test1   is_ms_shipped
usp_test2   test1   is_published
usp_test2   test1   is_schema_published
usp_test2   test1   modify_date
usp_test2   test1   name
usp_test2   test1   object_id
usp_test2   test1   parent_object_id
usp_test2   test1   principal_id
usp_test2   test1   schema_id
usp_test2   test1   type
usp_test2   test1   type_desc
```

**References:**
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1060325-149-1.aspx

Comment: Awesome, works great, I just updated WHERE contidion to "in ('V', 'P', 'F')"

Comment: But it gives only partial result.

Comment: i created two stored procs in my empty DB as test case (you can see above),it shows me both stored procs

Comment: For 1 database it seems to work fine. Unfortunately no external columns are shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`, check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) for further details

```
SELECT  referenced_entity_name + '.' + referenced_minor_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.Proc1', 'OBJECT')
WHERE referenced_minor_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This lists lots of results, but not all. Joins and inserts are not shown.

Comment: It does show most joins, however, not when you join across a linked server. It will only list inserts when you have explicitly specified the column names on the `INSERT`.